# What printing technique can I use to print a poster that is too vibrant to print using screen printing?

Tags: print-design, posters, screen-printing

I've got a poster design that I wish to print. But provided that poster has multiple colors that won't go good for a screen print (further, I would like to restrict screen printing to t-shirts), is there any printing technique that can be used? Please note that, one I'm a DIY guy, and two I don't want the prints on a large scale and hence won't prefer the idea of going for offset printing or some Print-on-Demand printing firm. Please let me know even if there is some inkjet printer or the like that you use that gives out good prints of A3 size at least. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind posting the design and size? We may be able to direct you with an excellent solution.

Comment: I confess that I am a little confused, since vibrant colors are *more easily achievable* using custom inks, this is something that is easier with screen printing than with offset press. Serigraphs are frequently upwards of 10 individual color passes and AFAIK a screen printing process. Registration is going to be crucial no matter how many colors past 1 you use and the only decision you need make is whether you need to use halftone screen or just threshold stencils.  No reason you can't use both of course.

Comment: @graphicsman I'm sorry but this one's for a client and hence can't be disclosed unless they permit (which according to the SLA is upon print and delivery).

Comment: @horatio Well, in my line of apologies, I'm sorry for I could not elaborate my problem that well but what I intended to mean with vibrant was that there is a gradient in the poster that ranges between like 8 vividly different colors (yes I know that sounds weird but that's what they asked for) along with the rest of the type and other stuff on it. And yes, I'm not a print pro. So I might be wrong about my decision to discard screen printing. But provided that I don't need the prints in large number, how cost effective would it be to use screen printing in such a scenario?

Comment: how is the poster created? Is it actually a digital image file? Are there really 8 inks or is it just RGB (3) or CMYK(4)? Or is it CMYK+individual spot color(s)? These are important considerations, because of color gamut: the range of possible colors is restricted by the inks used to build it.

Comment: If its for a client why are you not going to outsource it if you are not prepared to print it from the info I am gathering?  Do you plan to get into printing with this design?  Are you asking us what is a solution than to produce the poster as a shirt?  If you have a quality design I would suggest finding someone that does DTG printing and have them do it.  I say this by what I am seeing you post.

Comment: @horatio Well there are not 8 inks. Its a digital image file created using the CMYK(4) colors.

Comment: @graphicsman Well, as you guessed, yes, I am new to the printing business (though I've been into designing for quite some time now) and don't have that much of knowledge about it. As far as outsourcing the printing is concerned, I have this time thought of giving it a try myself as I've got enough time as I believe to experiment and fail. Plus I'm from India and DGT printing is not that prominent yet here. So if I outsource it to some agency like moo.com that's gonna cost me more than I'd be getting per unit.

Comment: Well just understand that if you are looking into starting this on your own you would need around 5-10k USD for decent equipment.  I would wait before you built a clientele and become knowledgeable with the process before just diving into it.  By that last comment your company life span would be no more than a year per statistics.  Plan smart and learn.  There is no reason to just dive in.  Contact around an see if you can outsource your work to a reputable company.

Comment: Agreed. I understand the risk. And of course would try to seek as much help and knowledge as possible before I just dive in. Plus I'm quite young (22 now) at this stage and have a long way to go. But I simultaneously seek to grab the market that is as of yet just beginning to bud in the subcontinent. Hence the risk appetite is going to be there.

Comment: in that case then "yes" to john's answer: cmyk printing is probably a good choice. It is four very specific inks and can be done, at least roughly, by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously you're limited by the equipment you have at your disposal, but have you considered CMYK screen printing? You will need a 4 color press with precise registration, but it is entirely possible to do: [CMYK Screen Printing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lOAf7nmE5M)

Consumer level wide format inkjet printers are available if you're looking to buy one, in my experience Epson is generally regarded as the best quality. Unfortunately, they can get rather pricey: [Epson Artisan 1430 Inkjet Printer](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Product.do?sku=C11CB53201&BV_UseBVCookie=yes). This printer can print larger than A3, up to 13" x 19".

If that is out of your price range, I would just consider going to a local print shop and asking for a price quote.

Comment: If you have any further idea, can you please inform me about how the screens are prepared for a CMYK screen printing? Are they prepared the same way as for any ordinary screen printing and the color (specifically the Key color) creates the necessary tone, or are they prepared in some distinctive way?

Comment: @ikartik90, I have never actually done a CMYK screen print, it's on my list of things to try out. Screen preparation as far as I've researched is no different. The tricky part is the color separation, which I believe can be done in Photoshop. You'll need special inks for this type of print as well.

Comment: @ikartik90 I would create a new thread since the preparation of plates is a different topic than what you asked.  It would help more in the future, too.

Comment: @graphicsman Please do share the link to the thread here once you're done. Thanks.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16512/prepare-a-design-for-cmyk-printing

Comment: In light of the fact that his source image is a cmyk digital file, then CMYK is a good choice. It is possible to take the image to a pre-press place, or even a commercial printing firm and have them create 4 films to whatever line-screen makes sense and then he can use the films to make the screens himself. IIRC, screen printing requires film *positives*. In the "olden days" I used to get random film seps for 5-10$ each set but that was usually a bulk job and smaller than 8x10.

Answer (score 2):

John has a great solution with Epson.  Personally I run the Workforce 1100, if you watch Staples they go on sale every other year for 149.99.  Last time I bought two.  I also picked up [BlackMax](http://www.silkscreeningsupplies.com/film-positive-ink) to print a plate for each CMYK.  Do exactly what John's video recommends.  In all I think I walked out with a couple hundred bucks in equipment.

**EDIT:**
video on setup with [BlackMax](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eH-TdY68dkk)

Comment: Have you ever done a CMYK print? @ikartik90 asked for more detail in a comment to my answer, but I hesitate to offer advice on something I've only read about/watched videos on. Any advice based on first hand experience would be multitudes better than what I can offer.

Answer (score 1):

It's really impossible to answer this question without knowing the specifics of your question. But let's start by talking about 'vibrant' and what that means.

I'm going to assume you mean it's a bright, highly saturated color.

Your main options:

1. Traditional 4-color printing. This is your CMYK process. There's a limit to the range of colors CMYK can make and perhaps isn't going to be as 'vibrant' as you want.
2. CMYK+more. There are several techniques for printing CMYK inks, plus typically a few additional colors to increase the range of reproducible colors. "Hexachrome" is a popular model which uses a total of 6 colors. Some higher-end ink jet printers also use a 6-color system (Epson makes several).
3. Spot colors. A 'spot' color is basically any custom mixed color. This is where the truly vibrant colors can come from as you can create colors that fall way outside of CMYK, including metallic ink, fluorescent colors, etc.

So that's the ink-options.

On top of that is actual printing options. You typically will have 3 options: offset printing, screen printing, and digital printing.

Offset printing is the cheapest option for large quantities (per unit cost is lowest).

Screen printing is also cheaper per unit the more you make, but is a viable option for short run posters and t-shirts and the like.

Digital printing (basically commercial ink jet printers) is the more expensive per-unit, but allows you to do very short runs.

So, hopefully some part of that answer will help you. Again, though, without knowing exactly what you mean by 'vibrant' colors, it's really impossible for us to give you specific advice.

Comment: Hi, I've explained to @horatio in the question comments of what I mean by vibrant (though it was my bad of not using some better descriptive adjectives). Please go through the same and see if you can help me further with the solution. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want to print in CMYK. So, any of the above are options. You can screen print in CMYK, you can pay an offset printer to do it, or just go find a color ink jet printer (all of which can do CMYK).